# Code formating without having to spacebar x4 before each line

Tags: support, code-formatting, editor

Why can't I just enclose code in code /code tags?

There must be something simpler than spacebar x4 in front of each line, no?

```
#!/bin/bash

echo ************************BEGIN LOG******************************
date +"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S $HOSTNAME"
cp -f /scripts/original/clamscans.log /scripts
find /public/public/clamscans/. -exec grep -n FOUND /dev/null {} \;>>clamscans.log
mail somedude@someplace.com < clamscans.log
tar cvf dailyresults.tar /public/public/clamscans/*.txt
gzip -f dailyresults.tar
mv -f /public/public/clamscans/*.txt /scripts/lastnite
echo end log entry
```

Comment: I wonder if whoever's giving the minus points might explain what's wrong with my question?

Comment: @micah, it's probably because this question is about StackOverflow itself, so it belongs on the meta site.

Comment: ok, that makes sense. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a button above this code edit window that looks like 1's and 0's.  Highlight all your code and click that button and it will indent it for you.

This probably should be on meta.

Comment: Cool! I didn't even notice it was right in front of my face like that. I was distracted by the big "How to Format" widget on the right that led me to several sub places going into copious detail yet never showing me how to do this simple task.

Comment: Learn something new every day. Not the button, the fact you could just space 4x for code :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use html tag pre and code or select your text and hit the button with 0s and 1s over the text field.

Comment: code tags don't properly handle the #!/bin/bash line. Treats it like a H1 tag er something. However, the pre /pre solution does seem to work. Thank you.

Comment: Do **not** use <pre><code> for this.

Answer (score 0):

Select the code and hit ctrl-k.